# accessing files on SD card in android

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard

I want to display image from a sd card into image view

Following code works in emulator but does not work on actual phone

```
File f = new File(imgPath);

if (f.exists()) {
   imgView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath("/mnt/sdcard/abc.jpg") ));

} else {

   imgView.setImageResource( R.drawable.image_abasent);

}
```

abc.jpg is put in emulator sd card sdk folder using DDMS 
I have also put abc.jpg directly on SD card through USB connection

I have added following permission too in the manifest file (but while installing from apk permission is not asked though)

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Still on phone the desired image is not accessible. 
What else is to be added or modified?

Comment: you should post the logcat or the entire manifest. maybe the uses-permission is not placed right in your manifest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please paste your manifest and also for accessing the SDCard you must use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` since `/mnt/sdcard/` would be a hardcoded solution and may not work on some devices or android builds.

Comment: To add to Ovidiu's post read up on how to access external storage here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal